# Copying text into the iPhone's system

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an app that generates some text and I would the user to be able to copy it using the tap of a button so that he can paste it somewhere else in the iPhone.

I would also like to be able to access any text that the user had already copied from another app on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`UIPasteboard`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008243-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) class might be exactly what you're looking for.

**EDIT**

Here's a brief example:

```
NSString *myString = @"Text to be copied";
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:myString];
```

Comment: So how exactly do I use the UIPasteBoard?

Comment: @YoussefSami check my edit and [this tutorial](http://jasapplications.com/Blog_files/Copy-Text-using-UIPasteBoard.html)